# C# - List<T>.Remove() always deletes the first object on the list

Tags: c#, .net, equality, generic-list, iequalitycomparer

Working in Visual Studio 2008 (C#)...
I use a List collection to store instances of my custom class (Shift).

I want to delete a certain shift from the list by using the Remove method.

But List.Remove() always deletes the first item it finds.

I've implemented the IComparable interface for my Shift, I thought this would be enough, then I added an implementation of IEqualityComparer, and it still has no effect.

Here's the excerpt with my implementation:

> region IComparable Members
>
> ```
>     public int CompareTo(object obj)
>     {
>         Shift s1 = this;
>         Shift s2 = (Shift)obj;
>         if (s1.start.time != s2.start.time)
>             return s1.start.CompareTo(s2.start);
>         else
>             return s1.end.CompareTo(s2.end);
>     }
> ```
>
> endregion
>
> region IEqualityComparer Members
>
> ```
>     public bool Equals(Shift x, Shift y)
>     {
>         
>         if ((x.opening) != (y.opening)) return false;
>         if ((x.closing) != (y.closing)) return false;
>         if (!x.opening) if (x._start != y._start) return false;
>         if (!x.closing) if (x._end != y._end) return false;
>         if (x.when != y.when) return false;
>         if (x.day != y.day) return false;
>         if (x.EmployeeID != y.EmployeeID) return false;
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     public int GetHashCode(Shift obj)
>     {
>         return obj.ToString().ToLower().GetHashCode();
>     }
> ```
>
> endregion

And yet, still - when the List contains two shifts, say "8:00 - 15:00"; "12:00 - 16:00", calling Remove("12:00-16:00") results in "8:00 - 15:00" getting removed, and the latter one remains in the collection!

What's wrong here? Thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override `object.GetHashCode` and `object.Equals`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return Equals(this, obj as Shift);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.GetHashCode(this);
}
```

You should also probably do a null check in `Equals(x, y)`.

Comment: You should also return false if obj.GetType() != GetType(), otherwise you risk doing equality checks against subclasses which may have more refined algorithms.

Comment: -1, He did not overload object.GetHashCode(), he implemented IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode(T).

Comment: BTW, I think he is simply misunderstanding the behavior of List.Remove() expecting it to perform a List.RemoveAll() (see my answer below).

Comment: OIC, I missed that THX.  It sounded like it was removing a 'first' one of several he wanted removed.  *confused*  I'm not sure how it was removing anything if he was using the default reference equality.  Anyway sounds like he's working now.

Answer (score 4):

`IComparable` is not normally used to compare for equality (it's used for ordering), so `List<T>.Remove()` ignores it.

`IEqualityComparer` is not an equivalent of `IComparable` for equality purposes. It is supposed to be implemented by a *comparer object* - that is, an object that compares *other objects* for equality. If you want equality comparisons to be inherent to your class, then you rather need to implement `IEquatable<T>`. Or just override `Object.Equals()` and `Object.GetHashCode()` on your class, without implementing any interfaces.

Comment: Actually Object.Equals() works just right! That seems like the simpliest option of all. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to determine equality and choose which object to remove, which will use `IEquatable<T>` if it's implemented on your object, otherwise, it will use reference equality.

You have two options to get the behavior you want:

1) Make Shift implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)  (not just override Object.Equals or make the method, but make Shift - `Shift : IEquatable<Shift>`)

2) Use [`List<T>.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With the example you provided, you're calling:

```
List<Shift>.Remove("12:00 - 16:00");
```

`"12:00 - 16:00"` in this case, is a `String` value and not an actual `Shift` object. Make sure that in your `CompareTo` method that you're code is properly casting the `String` value to a `Shift` object. Otherwise, when it compares start times...things could go haywire.

Comment: Justin, as a matter of fact I don't really pass a string parameter, this was sort of "pseudo-code" on my part just to show the concept. Sorry if that was ambiguous